# Asp.net disable action on Post Back page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've looked around and didn't find anuthing similar, what I'm looking for is a way to disable or stop whatever action that make the page post back on the page_load method according to some validation
example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
                'Validate here and stop the action
        End If
End Sub
```

I've already tried to end the request but in this way I can't tell the user whats going on

Comment: The page has *already* posted back and is now in the middle of the Load event. You'll have to do something else. One possibility is doing validation on the page with a Validation control, which uses javascript, or some other javascript. *That* can stop processing before the postback.

Comment: will what I want to validate is server side only thats why javascipt will not give me what I want in an easy way, so it must be server side and I wanted it to be in one place thats called all the time

Comment: You could use a Page Method (aka Web Method). JavaScript calls code behind to do work that can also return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If the page fails validation, then the whole idea that no post back WILL occur! So you as a general rule don't check in the post back for a validation that supposed to not allow the post back!!!

If validation and the validators are working correctly, then no post back can and should occur. Now if you want code behind to do some extra logic and processing and some extra testing?

The of course you allow the post back, and thus now in that button event code stub, or say dropdown list or whatever event code stub is being triggered? It is in THAT code that you can add additional validation.

So you might have a VERY nice regex validator that requires the user MUST enter a legal formatted email address. They then hit ok, and say you then run some code to check if the email is on-file, and at that point your code behind can:
Display a message on the screen, or even trigger a toast message (client side). Note that you CAN trigger nice toast message or client side script if that is the VERY last thing your code behind does, and this works rather well.

So yes, one can and will often have a mix between some validators on the page, and THEN some additional code "behind" that does and will run as a result of the post back having been allowed.

But, if validators (client side) are working, then you not have any post back to run, and thus you can't check anything at all anyway. If the validators are working correct, then no post back should occur at all.

However, as noted, if you need to write some additional logic for that button or control event? Then you let the post back occur, run that additonal logic, and display a message, or toast message or do whatever based on that input, and then the page will rendered again.

Comment: thats what I ended up doing, putting the extra valdiation on every event that I want to stop the code in, but what I was looking for is some kind of thing in one place so that I don't have to re-write my validation every time

Comment: Hum, busy right now, but I believe there is a way to "connect" the validations to extra buttons you drop on the form - but a button should not be able to post back if validation does not pass. I'll check this later today - you might have to live with the road you taken here.